# lmer error couldn't evaluate grouping factor

Tags: r, lme4, mixed-models

I am trying to fit a rather simple, linear nested model (teachers within schools) with about 700,000 datapoints (300,000 unique teacher ids; 60,000 school ids) as follows:

```
formula=outcome ~ Gender + covar1 + (1|schoolid/teacherid) 
fit=lmer(formula, data=myData)
```

I get the following error:

> Error: couldn't evaluate grouping factor teacherid:schoolid within
>   model frame: try adding grouping factor to data frame explicitly if
>   possible.

I am not sure what this means and how to correct this.

The following non-nested model however works perfectly fine:

```
formula=outcome ~ Gender + covar1 + (1|schoolid) +(1|teacherid) 
fit=lmer(formula, data=myData)
```

Please help!

Comment: I'm not sure what is causing this error, but try making a new variable for `teacherid` that has a unique name for every teacher in the dataset (if they don't already).  You can do this by combining `teacherid` with `schoolid` into a new variable.  I have done such work with `paste()` or `interaction()`.  Then you don't need the  "nested" style coding and can possibly avoid the error message.  (Read the last bullet [here](https://bbolker.github.io/mixedmodels-misc/glmmFAQ.html#nested-or-crossed) for an example of what I mean)

Comment: @aosmith - Thanks for editing the question to make it more readable. Also thanks a ton for the workaround you suggested. Based on what you said, I did the following: myData$teacher_school_ids_combo=do.call(paste, myData[c("teacherid","schoolid")]). And used the formula =Gender + covar1 + (1|teacher_school_ids_combo). The model was fitted without errors. Does this mean I don't need nested model now?

Comment: If `teacherid` has a unique name per individual in the dataset you don't need to use the explicit nesting coding and can use "crossed" coding.  Like `(1|schoolid) + (1|teacher_school_ids_combo)`.  (Note you still need `schoolid` as a separate random effect.)

Comment: Thanks @aosmith for pointing out that `schoolid` as separate random effect is needed. I tried `lmer` with `(1|schoolid) + (1|teacher_school_ids_combo)` in the formula and the model fitted. Not sure what was incorrect with the original formulation of `(1+schoolid/teacherid)`.

Comment: For me, the issue was gone after restarting the R session. Not sure this was the reason, but it might have been the case that "evaluating  grouping factor" failed due to a lack of free memory...